# Trying to find author of short story called Man Alone

Tags: story-identification

I'm not certain that is the title but the plot was about a guy who had been modified with machinery equipment to live on Mars. He was a reluctant 'experiment' at first but once he arrived he was "operational" and became perfectly suited to function and turned his back on his creators.

Comment: There are six stories on ISFDB called "Man Alone" - William Scarff (1959), Don Berry (1958), Wolcott Gibbs (1932), Algis Budrys (1959) and Drew Arrants (2008). When did you read it and where did you read it?

Comment: That's five. Actually four, because Scarff = Budrys.

Comment: @user14111 - My maths apparently leaves something to be desired

Answer (score 12):

It appears that you have slightly mis-remembered the title.  I think you are describing "[**Man Plus**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1580)" by Frederik Pohl.  It is the story of an astronaut who undergoes body modifications to enable him to live on Mars.  He was originally the [backup astronaut](http://opinionsofawolf.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/book-review-man-plus-by-frederik-pohl-bottom-of-tbr-pile-challenge/) and didn't really want to do it.

> *The first Earthling reworked into a Martian would be Roger Torraway.
> Martian instead of Earthling since everything on him had to be
> reworked in order to survive on Mars.  His organic skin is stripped
> off and made plastic.  His eyes are replaced by large, buglike red
> ones.  He is given wings to gather solar power, not to fly.  All of
> which is organized and run by his friend, the computer on his back.
> Who was this man? What was his life like? How did he survive the
> transformation to become more than human and help us successfully
> colonize Mars?*