# Is "The Titan" (2018) based on previous works?

Tags: adaptations, the-titan

The 2018 Netflix movie *The Titan* does not credit any previous works as its source material. However, [the movie's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Titan_(film)) lists [*Man Plus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Plus), a 1976 novel by Frederik Pohl as a "similar uncredited novel". The premises sound remarkably similar, though I have not read *Man Plus*. Is *The Titan* based on this or any other work? I'm mostly interested in finding out whether the writers/director/producers have cited other works as inspiration during interviews or elsewhere.

I've done some more digging and it seems there are at least a few who feel *Man Plus* and *The Titan* are very similar, though I haven't been able to find any citations to these claims. One such example is [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20181025221835/http://bobmayer.com/the-titan-and-man-plus-same-idea-different-stories/).

Also, I just discovered this question may be a duplicate. At the very least, it is similar to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184663/book-similar-to-the-netflix-movie-the-titan).

Comment: All the sources I can find show Arash Amel as being the writer of an original idea script. No interviews indicate anything about inspiration.

Comment: @JohnP same here. Grace of Monaco by Amel was kind of an inspiration.

Comment: I have read the novel, and it was considerably better than the movie. As stated earlier genetic manipulation was substituted for robotic/bionic enhancement. The story line of the movie was VERY close to the novel. Quite a few reviews just don't get the point of the movie, loss of humanity/what does being human require/human relationships etc. The actual colonisation of the moon Titan was not the focus. Also the novel had similar world wide wars/stability issues, although the novel was focused on the continuation of the cold war between the USA and USSR.

Comment: I read a book as a kid that was exactly this story including Titan being the destination. I just can’t remember the name of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't read *Man Plus* either but I found something else. According to IndieWire ([here](https://www.indiewire.com/2018/03/the-titan-review-netflix-sam-worthington-tries-to-live-on-saturn-in-weak-netflix-sci-fi-thriller-1201945198/)),

> Max Hurwitz’s (Screenplay of the movie) script, based on the writer **Arash Amel**'s idea with a slight change/suggestion: *Instead of changing an alien place to better accommodate people, why not change people to better accommodate an alien place?*

Also mentioned [here](https://deadline.com/2015/08/sam-worthington-ruth-wilson-the-titan-brian-kavanaugh-jones-automatik-ben-pugh-rory-aitken-1201508406/):

> Lennart Ruff directs the project, based on a original story by Amel (Grace Of Monaco).

So, apparently the book/novel on which the movie is based hasn't been mentioned anywhere, but it sure is based on a story by Amel.

Comment: Grace of Monaco was written by Arash Amel, but it's a biopic about Grace Kelly. I don't know much about her, but I dont think Grace Kelly was ever part of genetic experiements that would enable her to travel to Titan. I think indiewire meant to say that this is an original idea by Arash Amel, writer of Grace of Monaco.

Comment: @Sethen I searched around a bit more and, yeah, you're right. It was based on Amel's idea and not his book. Making the changes rightaway. Sorry! :p